# Key size vs output size of a MAC

Tags: mac, key-size

What is more important, in terms of security, the size of the MAC or the size of the key that it uses? I'm asking this because I have to answer the following homework question:

> What is more secure? A MAC with a 12-byte key and 6-byte MAC length,
>   or a MAC with a 8-byte key and 12-byte MAC length?

For the first one, it's easier to find a pre-image of the result. But for the second one, it's easier to find the key.

Comment: Hint: Is finding pre-images a problem for the security of a MAC (ie can you use it to break the security definition)?

Comment: The answer to the quoted question is not well defined. It's trivial to construct pairs of MAC schemes, such that either direction is true.

Answer (score 2):

The obvious issue is the probability of guessing the key, and the probability of guessing the MAC.

But there's also a qualitative difference.  Suppose you have learned a message/authenticator pair $(m, a)$ where $a = H_k(m)$.

- You can test a guess $k_0$ for the key *offline* by testing whether $a \stackrel?= H_{k_0}(m)$.

  **The feasibility of finding the key $k$ depends on how much money the *adversary* has to commit to an *offline* key search.**
- You can test a guess $a'_0$ for the authenticator $a' = H_k(m')$ of a forged message $m'$ only by submitting $(m', a'_0)$ *online* to the legitimate system and seeing how the legitimate system reacts.

  **The feasibility of forging an authenticator $a'$ this way depends on how much bandwidth the *legitimate system* has to accept *online* forgery attempts.**